# Dart: Dynamic usage of polymer-ui-tabs and polymer-ui-pages does not work

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

we would like to use polymer-ui-tabs and polymer-ui-pages dynamically.
the following static example works fine (attribute selected is set properly, on-polymer-select event is fired)

```dart
  <polymer-ui-tabs selected="{{selectedTab}}" on-polymer-select="{{mymethod}}">
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
    <span>Three</span>
  </polymer-ui-tabs>

  <polymer-ui-pages selected="{{selectedTab}}" on-polymer-select="{{mymethod2}}" flex>
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
    <span>Three</span>
  </polymer-ui-pages>
```

When building the dom dynamically, the on-polymer-select event is never fired and the attribute selected is only set for polymer-ui-tabs.

```dart
@CustomTag('ve-result-dyn')
 class ResultElementDyn extends PolymerElement  {

 Element tabElement;
 Element pageElement;
 @published dynamic selectedTab;

 ResultElementDyn.created(): super.created() {
   buildDom();
 }

 @override
 void ready() {
   selectedTab = '1';
 }

 void setSelectedInTab() {
   print('in setSelectedInTab $selectedTab');
 }

 void setSelectedInPage() {
   print('in setSelectedInPage $selectedTab');
 }

 void buildDom(){
   print('in buildDom');

  tabElement = new Element.tag('polymer-ui-tabs');
  tabElement.setAttribute("id","dtabs");
  tabElement.setAttribute("selected","{{selectedTab}}");
  tabElement.setAttribute("on-polymer-select","{{setSelectedInTab}}");

  Element spanelement = new SpanElement();
  spanelement.innerHtml = 'One';
  tabElement.children.add(spanelement);

  spanelement = new SpanElement();
  spanelement.innerHtml = 'Two';
  tabElement.children.add(spanelement);

  spanelement = new SpanElement();
  spanelement.innerHtml = 'Three';
  tabElement.children.add(spanelement);

  this.shadowRoot.append(tabElement);
  this.shadowRoot.append(new DivElement());

  pageElement = new Element.tag('polymer-ui-pages');
  pageElement.setAttribute("id","dpages");
  pageElement.setAttribute("selected","{{selectedTab}}");
  pageElement.setAttribute("on-polymer-select","{{setSelectedInPage}}");

  spanelement = new SpanElement();
  spanelement.innerHtml = 'Page 1';
  pageElement.children.add(spanelement);

  spanelement = new SpanElement();
  spanelement.innerHtml = 'Page 2';
  pageElement.children.add(spanelement);

  spanelement = new SpanElement();
  spanelement.innerHtml = 'Page 3';
  pageElement.children.add(spanelement);

  this.shadowRoot.append(pageElement);

}
```

Any idea?
Best regards,   Anja

Comment: Thanks for using polymer_elements. I'll try it soon. Can't promise how soon.

Comment: I finally found time to look into this. This is an interesting attempt. I never tried to create mustache binding at runtime. I'll try to find out if and how this works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this. I still don't know if it is possible to make Polymer evaluate mustache expressions created at runtime though.

#### Update

Polymer 0.15.0 adds `injectBoundHtml`. 
The used expressions must already be used somewhere so Smoke knows to generate code for them.
See https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web/uqri0fpGH10/dPm169WUiUwJ for more details.

#### Update end

Only a few small changes were necessary.
I commented out the original line and added the new code the line below.

You can save the result of `StreamSubscription selSubscr = tabElement.onPolymerSelect.listen((e) => setSelectedInTab(e));` and call `selSubscr.cancel();` when you are no longer interested in this event.

```dart
library polymer_tabs_issue;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:polymer_ui_elements/polymer_ui_tabs/polymer_ui_tabs.dart';
import 'package:polymer_ui_elements/polymer_ui_pages/polymer_ui_pages.dart';

@CustomTag('ve-result-dyn')
class ResultElementDyn extends PolymerElement {

  PolymerUiTabs tabElement;
  PolymerUiPages pageElement;
  @published dynamic selectedTab;

  ResultElementDyn.created() : super.created() {
    buildDom();
  }

  @override
  void ready() {
    selectedTab = '1';
  }

  void setSelectedInTab(CustomEvent e) {
    print('in setSelectedInTab $selectedTab, ${e.detail}');
  }

  void setSelectedInPage(CustomEvent e) {
    print('in setSelectedInPage $selectedTab, ${e.detail}');
  }

  void buildDom() {
    print('in buildDom');

    tabElement = new Element.tag('polymer-ui-tabs');
    tabElement.setAttribute("id", "dtabs");
    //tabElement.setAttribute("selected", "{{selectedTab}}");
    tabElement.bind('selected', new PathObserver(this, 'selectedTab'));
    //tabElement.setAttribute("on-polymer-select", "{{setSelectedInTab}}");
    tabElement.onPolymerSelect.listen((e) => setSelectedInTab(e));

    Element spanelement = new SpanElement();
    spanelement.innerHtml = 'One';
    tabElement.children.add(spanelement);

    spanelement = new SpanElement();
    spanelement.innerHtml = 'Two';
    tabElement.children.add(spanelement);

    spanelement = new SpanElement();
    spanelement.innerHtml = 'Three';
    tabElement.children.add(spanelement);

    this.shadowRoot.append(tabElement);
    this.shadowRoot.append(new DivElement());

    pageElement = new Element.tag('polymer-ui-pages');
    pageElement.setAttribute("id", "dpages");
    //pageElement.setAttribute("selected", "{{selectedTab}}");
    pageElement.bind('selected', new PathObserver(this, 'selectedTab'));

    //pageElement.setAttribute("on-polymer-select", "{{setSelectedInPage}}");
    pageElement.onPolymerSelect.listen((e) => setSelectedInPage(e));

    spanelement = new SpanElement();
    spanelement.innerHtml = 'Page 1';
    pageElement.children.add(spanelement);

    spanelement = new SpanElement();
    spanelement.innerHtml = 'Page 2';
    pageElement.children.add(spanelement);

    spanelement = new SpanElement();
    spanelement.innerHtml = 'Page 3';
    pageElement.children.add(spanelement);

    this.shadowRoot.append(pageElement);
    //this.templateInstance.firstNode.append(pageElement);
  }
}
```