# Data binding for dynamically created element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In a polymer element I can bind a property like this:
`<input type="text" value="{{value}}">`
But if I create the html element dynamically in the script:
`TextInputElement newElement = new TextInputElement();`
How can I achieve the binding?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at

- [Creating a dataList programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554258)
- [Dart: Dynamic usage of polymer-ui-tabs and polymer-ui-pages does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083760)

there was a similar question for Polymer.js recently with a simpler solution ([Data binding for dynamically generated HTML in Polymer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783778)) but I haven't seen anything similar for Polymer.dart yet.
I'll try to find something tomorrow, it's rather late here already ...

I created this issue http://dartbug.com/21029
This is fixed now with `injectBoundHtml`. 
See also https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web/uqri0fpGH10/dPm169WUiUwJ for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I can make without, but I think it would be a nice feature.

Comment: 21029 is fixed with the new Polymer release https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/uqri0fpGH10

Answer (score 0):

I use this workaround (polymer 0.15.5+4):

```
var template = new TemplateElement()
..setInnerHtml("<p>Reversed: {{ reversed }}</p>");
var fragment = this.instanceTemplate(template);
this.shadowRoot.append(fragment);
```

But it seems rather complex for me and i've not found more elegant solution for a while.

I feel confused by  Günter's phrase "The used expressions must already be used somewhere so Smoke knows to generate code for them." from [Dart: Dynamic usage of polymer-ui-tabs and polymer-ui-pages does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083760/dart-dynamic-usage-of-polymer-ui-tabs-and-polymer-ui-pages-does-not-work) thread. Can somebody from this thread light this moment?

Comment: lf `reversed` isn't already used anywhere in a binding (which is not injected but static)  Smoke doesn't generate code and the binding will not work in HTML added dynamically  with injectBoundHtml.

Comment: Thank you, Günter. Do you know - is there are any program means to make smoke generate missing code at runtime?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. They can't generate code for expressions they don't know about.

Comment: I generate form dymanically and i'd like to tell "smoke" somehow, that I need access some properties in model. Something like "smoke.registerProperty(targetModel, 'path.to.property.i.want.to.use.in.binding')"...

Comment: Then you need to add this expression somewhere as a dummy expression statically.

Comment: The thing is that I do not know expressions before form creation, i want to create form from metadata describing it. So I'll dig polymer expressions and smoke the smoke :)